Flexbox wrap in flexbox no wrap
I would like to add a flexbox with wrap at the end of a flexbox with no wrap. In order to wrap only elements in the second flexbox if space is missing.
I made a snippet to show you what happen, it's here : codePen
the example :
<div class="container">
      <div class="block ">Block1</div>
      <div class="block ">Block2</div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="block ">Block3</div>
        <div class="block ">Block4</div>
      </div>
    </div>

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.block{
  flex-shrink:0;
  height : 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Is it a way to make the second flexbox really wrapping ?
